# url at the end of description

Tags: glossaries, urls

I would like to add an url at the end of each description.

```
\documentclass[12pt,BCOR=15mm]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[xindy,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\GlsSetXdyCodePage{duden-utf8}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\newglossaryentry{glossaries}
{
  name=Glossaries,
  description={...},
  url={http://test.de}
}


\glsaddall
\printglossary[title={\LaTeX-Pakete},toctitle={\LaTeX-Pakete}]

\end{document}
```

The output is:

> Glossaries ...

and I need a new line with the url:

> Glossaries ...
>
> http://...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the user keys to store additional information. For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,BCOR=15mm]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[xindy,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\GlsSetXdyCodePage{duden-utf8}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{glossaries}
{
  name=Glossaries,
  description={...},
  user1={http://test.de}
}

\newglossaryentry{tildeurl}
{
  name=tildeurl,
  description={...},
  user1={http://test.de/\string~abc}
}

\newglossaryentry{percenturl}
{
  name=percenturl,
  description={...},
  user1={http://test.de/\%7Eabc}
}

\newglossarystyle{url}
{% based on list style (adapt as required)
  \setglossarystyle{list}%
    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
          \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]
       \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space##2%
    \ifglshasfield{useri}{##1}{\glspar
     \glsletentryfield{\thisurl}{##1}{useri}%
     \expandafter\url\expandafter{\thisurl}}{}}%
}

\setglossarystyle{url}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall
\printglossary[title={\LaTeX-Pakete},toctitle={\LaTeX-Pakete}]

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting glossary]